# Branch Dialogue - How to continue

Tags: python-3.x

Working on a game, just as a side project to get more familiar with coding. Wanted branching dialogue but I'm wondering what solution would be the best approach for something like this. Currently it looks like it will be a lot of if/elif/else statements.

This code works, but I think it's going to get messy very quickly so I'm thinking there must be an easier approach.

```
def choosePath():
    path = ""
    while True:
        path = input("What will you do?\n--> ").lower()
        if path in "abcde":
            return path
        elif path not in "abcde":
            print("Invalid command, try again\n")

choice1 = choosePath()

if choice1 == "a":
    print("text")
    choice2 = choosePath()
    if choice2 == "a":
        print("new text")
elif choice1 == "b":
    print("text")
if choice1 == "c":
    print("text")
```

Comment: Most basic reccommendation I can make is seperate each path to a function and call it when necessary. Of course you will have to endure some level of `if/else`ing, but at least that would make your code more readable which is just as important

Comment: Instead of doing it this way, you're thinking Path to start as a function and maybe do PathA_1, PathB_1, PathC_1 and just call the function depending on which function was previous ran by using if/else as well? 

Is that right?

Comment: Something like that. I believe that encapsulating the diferent paths in functions makes it easy to read and understand what's going on. Also, if for example, choosing 'a' and then choosing 'b' is the same as choosing 'c' from the first place, you save your self some work by calling the same function for both cases

Answer (score 0):

The problem with branching dialogue and programming languages is that dialogue works best with a *script* - like, a theater, script, so you can jump from point A to point B and et cetera. Some programming languages let you do this with `goto` statements and labels, but this is a dangerous practice and it should usually be avoided where it is possible (and even then, it isn't possible in python).

Nesting your script is a good start, and provides a reasonably intuitive system of branching dialogue. The problem is, it develops many levels of indentation too quickly, which is what you've discovered.

One possible way of addressing that is to have only one later of `if` statements, and instead create a variable (or variable*s*) that specifies which dialogue branch the user is on. For example:

```
current_path = None

# unconditional path
print("First line of dialogue")
print("Second line of dialogue")
# branch point
choice = choosePath():
current_path = {"a": "path1", "b": "path2", "c": "path3", ...}[choice]

# branch A
if current_path == "path1":
    print("First line of dialogue in branch A")
    print("Second line of dialogue in branch A")
    # branch A branch point
    choice = choosePath():
    current_path = {"a":"path1-sub1", ...}

# branch B
if current_path == "path2":
    print("First line of dialogue in branch B")
    print("Second line of dialogue in branch B")

# branch C
if current_path == "path3":
    print("First line of dialogue in branch C")
    print("Second line of dialogue in branch C")

# sub-branch of A
if current_path == "path1-sub1":
    print("new text")
...
```

This also allows for more creative/expansive branching, by using more complicated `if` conditions. It does require foresight and planning to set up branch names appropriately for it to work, though.

If you take this approach, I would advise reworking your `choosePath()` function to actually return an acceptable current path - for example feed it in a dictionary of options to path names, and it returns the appropriate path name:

```
def choosePath(choices_dict):
    # truncate the list of displayed letter options depending on the number of choices
    letter_options = "abcde"[:len(choices_dict)]

    # zip together dict keys and associated letter options in a tuple
    # [('a', choices_dict.keys()[0]), ('b', choices_dict.keys()[1]), ...]
    options_correspondence = zip(letter_options, choices_dict.keys())

    # make a list of lines to print that show the user what their choices are
    # in the format "letter": "choice"
    displayedOptions = [f"  {letter}: {choice}" for letter, choice in options_correspondence]

    # make a dict such that the letter typed corresponds to the path to take
    # if that letter is typed
    choiceOptions = {letter:choices_dict[choice] for letter, choice in options_correspondence}

    # tell the user what the options are
    print("Here are your options:")
    print("\n".join(displayedOptions))

    # continuously ask the user for their choice until their choice is valid
    # (letter_options.split('') is used to make sure that, for example, 'ab'
    #    is not a valid input - must be asingle letter).
    user_choice = ""
    while user_choice not in letter_options.split(''):
        user_choice = input(f'Which will you choose? (enter any of "{letter_options}"): ')

    # return choice corresponding to user input
    return choiceOptions[user_choice]

...
current_path = choosePath({
    "Go towards the forest":"forestpath", 
    "Go towards the town":"townpath"
})
```

Comment: Lot of digest here. The key:value is a great idea, I haven't learned much about that yet. The more confusing part is the dictionary within the function but it's just because I'm learning and haven't seen anything quite like that yet. I really appreciate the suggestions!

Comment: Admittedly, I made the dict-in-function bit more complicated than it probably needed to be. I've gone back and added comments to explain what each step of it does.